# Opening keyboard reduce size of view's and hides text of other view (React native)

Tags: react-native

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhyeU.png)

[when open keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLYhD.png)

```
function PINInsert({ navigation }){
  clearText = () => {
    _textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
  }

  var onoff = 0
  hideText = () => {
    if(onoff == 0){
      _textInput.setNativeProps({secureTextEntry: false});
      onoff = 1;
    }else{
      _textInput.setNativeProps({secureTextEntry: true})
      onoff = 0;
    }
  }

  return(
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container0}>
      <View style={PINInsertstyles.div0}>
        <View style={{
          alignContent: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"}}>
          <Image style={PINInsertstyles.flag} source={require('./assets/en.png')} />
        </View>
        <View style={{
          alignContent: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"}}>
          <Image style={PINInsertstyles.flag} source={require('./assets/br.png')} />
        </View>
        </View>
      <View style={PINInsertstyles.div1}>
        <View style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,   
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}>
          <Image style={PINInsertstyles.logo} source={require('./assets/headphone.png')} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>SoundFly</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={PINInsertstyles.div2}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <TextInput
              ref={component => _textInput = component}
              style={{
                height: 40,
                width: 200,
                margin: 5,
                marginTop: 20,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#ccc',
                fontSize: 20,
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
              }}
              maxLength={6}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              placeholder="PIN"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={hideText} >
              <Icon name="eye" size={20} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearText}
            style={{margin: 5, marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 5}}
            >
            <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 20}}>Clear text</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('banner')}
            style={{margin: 5, marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'purple', padding: 5}}
          >
            <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 20}}>Buscar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style= {{height: 50}}></View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};
```

```
const PINInsertstyles = StyleSheet.create({
  div0: {
    flex: 0.4,
    backgroundColor: '#00FFEC',
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
  },
  div1: {
    flex: 0.6,
    backgroundColor: '#00DCCC',    
    alignItems: "center",
    // justifyContent: "center"
  },
  div2: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#00BFBF',
    alignItems: "center",
    // justifyContent: "center"
  },
  flag: {
    height: 50,
    width: 80,
    margin: 5
  },
  logo:{
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    margin: 10,
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
})
```

How I want is "When open keyboard, whole views go up without some view reducing size of itself."
I've tried a lot of example but my start is really different comparing with them cause most example starts complaining about keyboard covers contents but mine just send Views up but resizing them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the styles too?

Comment: ......................added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get dimension of window using

```
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

And then, insert `justify-content: flex-end` to container0.
Add a view right inside KeyboardAvoidingView and set minHeight to window height.

Comment: Thank u so much!

Comment: Uhmm, 1 curiosity. I was thinking to develop more from this state. Like [link] (https://medium.com/@nickyang0501/keyboardavoidingview-not-working-properly-c413c0a200d4) this. I thought the problem to do this example was 'I can't even start how this example start. (My views goes up when open keyboard but reducing its size)'.

Now I want views to go up but ur solution is same thing what link says(add justifycontent: flex-end) but results are totally different. If I want my views go up without reducing its size, what should I do?